# How to limit the size of the back stack in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, out-of-memory

We are developing an Android app that contains very heavy views (it is used to present a company's catalog).

The design of the app has some flaws, mainly because we were "forced" to mimic as much as possible the existing iOS version of the app (I know, this is wrong). Now we are facing some memory issues (=OOM exceptions), mainly because the navigation is not very structured and we cannot enforce a "finite" depth for the navigation: at the moment the user can make the back stack grow as much as he wants.

Let me try to explain in a better way. In our app we have 4 sections `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. User can enter section `A`, open sub-section `A2` and then sub-sub section `A3`. He can do the same in `B`, with `B2` and `B3`. But he can also do something like this:

```
A -> A2 -> A3 -> B2 -> A3 -> B2 -> A3 -> ... !OOM Exception!
```

Unfortunately, we are not allowed to change design of the app.

How to prevent the app from creating many activities and having the stack size to grow too much? When the activity stops we do *as much cleanup as possible* (release resources, recycle bitmaps) but that just limits the size of the problem, it doesn't eliminate it.

We are now thinking about marking all the activities as **singleInstance**. What do you think about this (yes, it is ugly)? Or can we somehow constrain the stack size in some other smarter way?

Comment: Just a thought, but close out all the activities as the user navigates then use shared preferences to bring up the activity the user wants?

Comment: @njzk2 sometimes you have to deal with the devil for a greater good :P

Comment: @KristyWelsh this could be an interesting idea in fact

Comment: if you are going to completely ignore the native handling of the backstack, you may as well handle it completely yourself. You could remove all activities from the back stack, and just keep their names somewhere. Then catch the back button to start the previous activity in the stack. That would allow you to completely close an activity when you leave it.

Comment: Do you _need_ to maintain the back stack when switching the sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution we picked and that seems to work in a satisfactory way:

- When opening the main sections `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` we use an intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`. This approach ensures that we reset the stack whenever the user enters a main section. [In the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) in fact they suggest these flags in cases that can be related to the one we are facing:

  > This flag is generally used by activities that want to present a "launcher" style behavior: they give the user a list of separate things that can be done, which otherwise run completely independently of the activity launching them.
- to deal with the "chains of (d)oom" we are going to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. This way in a setting like this:

  ```
  A -> A2 -> A3 -> B2 ( -> A3 )
  ```

  when the user opens an `A3` activity, the stack is "collapsed" to this:

  ```
  A -> A2 -> A3
  ```

It is not perfect but reasonable, at least in our use cases.

Comment: *chains of (d)oom* should be come a thing